# Show Blank Row In WPF DataGrid when DataSet is Empty

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am running an SQL query on a SQL Server 2008 database.  The results from this query are displayed in a WPF DataGrid.  My code works great, except when the dataset is empty.  I want the user to be able to add new rows, but when the dataset is empty there is no empty row for the user to enter data into.  Below is my code:

```
        try
        {
            string accountQuery = "SELECT a.AccountName AS 'Account Name', a.AccountDesc AS 'Account Description', " +
                "a.AccountNumber AS 'Account #', b.AccountType AS 'Account Type', c.AccountName AS 'Account Parent' " +
                "FROM Accounts AS a INNER JOIN AccountType AS b ON a.AccountTypeID = b.AccountTypeID " +
                "LEFT OUTER JOIN Accounts AS c ON c.AccountID = a.AccountParentID " +
                "WHERE a.UserID = " + currentUserID;

            SqlDataReader accounts = null;
            SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(accountQuery, dbConnection);

            accounts = query.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable accountsTable = new DataTable();
            accountsTable.Load(accounts);

            this.GridAccounts.ItemsSource = accountsTable.DefaultView;

            accounts.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            // Close the DB if there was an error.
            if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                dbConnection.Close();
        }
```

If anybody can help me out with getting this empty row so the user can enter data, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can check the source first. if source you get from database is null, then you will add a new row into the GridView.

Comment: Maybe you can try this dataTable.Rows.Add(dataTable.NewRow());

Comment: I think that is for winforms.  There is no Rows property in the WPF datagrid to add rows to.

Comment: Rows property is not for DataGrid, but for DataTable

Comment: I am able to do this, only problem now is that I have the blank row AND I have the blank row for the user to add data to.  So, I have two blank rows.

Comment: I just thought of a work around for this.  If there is no rows in my dataset, I will manually add one, and change CanUserAddRows to false.  Then I only have one empty row.  Once the user adds valid data to this row, I will change CanUserAddRows to true again and leave it that way.  Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm just starting to get this, but this has worked so far.

```
    <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding UserAlerts}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" x:Name="UserAlertsGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Node ID" Binding="{Binding Node_id}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Threshold" Binding="{Binding Threshold}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type of Alert" Binding="{Binding TypeOfAlert}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Then to get the 'CanUserAddRows' to work, you need a default constructor in your ViewModel (where you do the bindings). If there is no default constructor, you won't get a blank row.

```
    class UserAlertViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly UserAlert _alertItem;

    public UserAlertViewModel()
    {
        _alertItem = new UserAlert();
    }

    public UserAlertViewModel(UserAlert alertItem)
    {
        _alertItem = alertItem;
    }
    public int Node_id
    {
        get { return _alertItem.Node_id; }
        set { _alertItem.Node_id = value; OnPropertyChanged("Node_id"); }
    }
    public double Threshold
    {
        get { return _alertItem.Threshold; }
        set { _alertItem.Threshold = value; OnPropertyChanged("Threshold"); }
    }
    public string TypeOfAlert
    {
        get { return _alertItem.TypeOfAlert; }
        set { _alertItem.TypeOfAlert = value; OnPropertyChanged("TypeOfAlert"); }
    }
}
```

And in the actual Window, you have to set the DataContext for the DataGrid

```
public UserAlertWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new ViewModel.UserAlertWindowViewModel();
        UserAlertsGrid.DataContext = new ViewModel.UserAlertWindowViewModel(this);
    }
```

And for updating the database when the user edits or deletes, check this link, it looks very promising.
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=566

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `CanUserAddRows` to `true` of `DataGrid`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListCollectionView` as source:

```cs
datagrid.CanUserAddRows = true;
datagrid.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(items_list);
```

and then following function to add empty row if it is not appeared:

```cs
public void AddNewRow()
{
    if (datagrid.Items is System.ComponentModel.IEditableCollectionViewAddNewItem items)
    {
        if (!items.IsAddingNew)
        {
            items.AddNew();
        }
    }
}
```